# Objective-C: displaying a value from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS application. 
I am trying to display a detected string from AVFoundation, "BarcodeNum". But it is not being displayed properly. Below is my code

FirstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *detectionString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *barcodeNum;
@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CGRect highlightViewRect = CGRectZero;
AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *barCodeObject;
self.detectionString = nil;
NSArray *barCodeTypes = @[AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                          AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode];

for (AVMetadataObject *metadata in metadataObjects) {
    for (NSString *type in barCodeTypes) {
        if ([metadata.type isEqualToString:type])
        {
            barCodeObject = (AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)[_prevLayer transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata];
            highlightViewRect = barCodeObject.bounds;
            self.detectionString = [(AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *)metadata stringValue];

            UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Barcode Detected" message:self.detectionString preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* yes = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                FirstViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"new"];

                [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

            UIAlertAction* no = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"No" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

            [alert addAction:yes];
            [alert addAction:no];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


            break;

        }

    }

    if (self.detectionString != nil)
    {
        _label.text = self.detectionString;
        self.barcodeNum = self.detectionString;
         break;


    }
    else
        _label.text = @"Barcode not found";
}

_highlightView.frame = highlightViewRect;
 }
```

SecondView.m

```
#import "SecondView.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface SecondView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation SecondView
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
   _label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstViewController.barcodeNum];
   //Not displaying the barcode number detected
}
@end
```

Comment: you are moving to FirstViewController, and then why are you checking the barcode value in secondView ? How you are moving to second view ?

Comment: you need to declare the properties in .h file if you want to access them from other classes

Comment: @Mr.T I am moving through modal in a AlertController button. I am looking for presenting the value detected in FirstView into a label in SecondView. I did declare the barcodeNum in FirstView "h" file. I didn't post the code for nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SecondView.viewDidLoad` you **create** a `FirstViewController` instance and try to gets its `barcodeNum` but how is that supposed to work? You just created a new instance - the firstViewController did not yet have any chance to set its `barcodeNum` property.

So far there is no information as to how `SecondView` and `FirstViewController` are related or connected. But *you* need to setup some kind of connection between those.

For example create a property in `SecondView` which holds an instance of `FirstViewController`. You then present the **same** `FirstViewController` and afterwards tell the `SecondView` to please refresh its label text.

Alternatively have your instance of `FirstViewController` do its calculation and then present the `SecondView` and in the `prepareForSegue` hand either your `barcodeNum` or the complete instance over.

Comment: So to answer your question, FirstView and SecondView are connected through modal. When the camera detects the barcode, it shows an alert controller that displays the barcode and asks the user if yes or no. If yes, the SecondView is presented. in SecondView I have a UILabel that I want to show the barcode in.

Comment: Okay, then that fits the last paragraph, create either a `barcodeNum` or a `firstViewController` property in `SecondView` and in `SecondView` read from that variable instead of creating a new `FirstViewController`

Comment: I am trying to read the value of a variable from another class. How will your solution work. I'm kinda confused.

Comment: @JohnDon 1. create either a `barcodeNum` or a `firstViewController` property in SecondView 2. assign something suitable to that property in `prepareForSegue` in your `FirstViewController` 3. use the property to get the text for the label

Comment: I did what you told me. I create a barcodeNum1 in SecondView and assigned the value barcodeNum from FirstView. preparForSugue is below:       `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"viewTwo"]) {
    
        SecondView *bc = [segue destinationViewController];
        
       
        bc.barcodeNum1 = self.barcodeNum;

    }
}`

Comment: Do I call the method anywhere in my code?

Comment: @JohnDon you have a segue called `viewTwo` that gets triggered from the `FirstViewController`? That method gets called after you tell the program to perform a segue of a given identifier.

Comment: Yes the identifier from FirstView to SecondView is called "viewTwo"

Comment: Then everything should work if you use the `barcodeNum1` in the `SecondView` `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You have been a great help luk2302. but its it no displaying anything :(

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the viewDidLoad to see wether or not the property is set!?

Comment: I am a bit new to iOS, how do I do that?

Comment: by navigating to your viedDidLoad method and clicking on the gray area on the left of the code (where the line numbers most of the times are) - then there should be blue pointy thingy indicating a breakpoint - if you run the app again and the execution reaches that point you are in debug mode and can view variables and the call stack etc.